# Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:

Tags: java, mysql, centos, haproxy, galera

We are getting error 
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:

Please find below

```html
8820042 WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
8820042 ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Already closed.
8820067 ERROR c.a.a.a.ExceptionHandlingAdvice - Exception occured at 2016-07-28T03:59:05.795 
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:544) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:420) ~[spring-tx-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:257) ~[spring-tx-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-tx-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) ~[spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy222.getAllCampaigns(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
 at com.adsizzler.adserver.controller.AdminCampaignController.GetCampaigns(AdminCampaignController.java:181) ~[classes/:na]
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor183.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261) [spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528) [catalina.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.36]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.36]
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed: 
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1435) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
 at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:502) ~[spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
 ... 76 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 435,883 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor133.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
 at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3715) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3604) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4155) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5357) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.setAutoCommit(DelegatingConnection.java:331) ~[commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.setAutoCommit(PoolingDataSource.java:317) ~[commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar:1.2.2]
 at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
 ... 79 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3161) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3615) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
 ... 88 common frames omitted
```

In the same time I am getting below error in MySql

```html
2016-07-28 03:52:49 22031 [Warning] Aborted connection 102085 to db: 'XXX' user: 'XXX' host: '10.139.0.167' (Got an error reading communication packets)
2016-07-28 04:06:57 22031 [Warning] Aborted connection 102512 to db: 'XXXX' user: 'XXXX' host: '10.139.0.167' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

When I have bind-address in my.cnf, application unable to connect to Galera mysql through HaProxy.

```html
[MYSQLD]
bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

Also Just I wanted to update I am using HAProxy between application and DD (MySql Galera). Please find below configuration.

```html
listen galera *:3307
#     balance source
     mode tcp
     option tcpka
     balance leastconn
     option mysql-check user haproxy
     default-server port 9200 inter 2s downinter 5s rise 3 fall 3 slowstart 60s maxconn 250 maxqueue 128 weight 100
     server db1 10.139.255.14:3306 check port 
     server db2 10.139.255.17:3306 check port 
     server db3 10.139.0.160:3306 check port
```

Please help to get it resolved.

Comment: Did you find any solution? Facing same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like network issue, check if you are able to ping, telnet the host as well as the jdbc port and service-id is correct

Comment: sometime due to network reconfiguration you might want to use the hostname instead of ip address

Comment: "(Got an error reading communication packets)", are you sure?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Also Just to inform We are using HAProxy between application and Database.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 5yo but I've encountered a very similar problem, although I've not been using any proxy and running both the app and DB on local machine. By the way, it seems that your app was able to access the DB and connect to it. The DB just aborted the connection because it received invalid packet.

In my case the problem was with the data source I was using: `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource` from the `org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.9.RELEASE`. I don't know why this data source kept failing, but using `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` from the `commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4` resolved the issue. Using `ComboPooledDataSource` from c3p0 works as well.